# Page Up/Down on Apple Magic Keyboard with iPad in Microsoft 365 Word

Tags: ms-office, magic-keyboard-ipad

I cannot for the life of me find the right key combo to perform page up/down with my Apple Magic Keyboard on the iPad in Microsoft 365 (Word). Command up/down work in other apps, but not in Office. Has anyone out there found a solution for this?

Comment: MS uses the common keys found on Windows keyboards, that are not often found on Mac keyboards. Annoying, I know. If your keyboard ha an "fn" key then that in combination with arrow up and down give you page up and down... at least it does on the last few MacBook Pros I've had...